# SQL Server - error after executing stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, transactions

When executing my stored procedure, why do I get the following error message?

> Msg 266, Level 16, State 2, Procedure spAddCustomer, Line 0 [Batch Start Line 21]
>   Transaction count after EXECUTE indicates a mismatching number of BEGIN and COMMIT statements. Previous count = 1, current count = 2.

Anything help, thanks.

Stored procedure code:

```
CREATE PROC spAddCustomer
    @FirstName VARCHAR = INPUT,
    @LastName VARCHAR = INPUT,
    @EmailAddress VARCHAR = INPUT,
    @PhoneNumber VARCHAR = INPUT
AS
BEGIN TRY
BEGIN TRANSACTION 
    INSERT INTO sales.CustomerPII (FirstName, LastName, EmailAddress, PhoneNumber)
    VALUES (@FirstName, @LastName, @EmailAddress, @PhoneNumber);

    COMMIT TRANSACTION
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
--Rows inserted still exist
--SELECT ERROR_NUMBER()
    --ROLLBACK TRANSACTION --Any transaction work will be undone
END CATCH;
```

Executed

```
EXEC spAddCustomer 'FirstTest', 'LastTest', 'EmailTest', 'AddressTest';
```

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : declaring VARCHAR without (length)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length) - you should **always** provide a length for any `varchar` variables and parameters that you use. For parameter, if you *omit* the explicit length, you get a parameter of **exactly ONE character** in length - which is typically not what you want .....

Comment: add `BEGIN` after `AS` and add `END` at the end of the store procedure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Un-comment this line:

```
ROLLBACK TRANSACTION --Any transaction work will be undone
```

Comment: I agree with @ikram. It appears that execution is going into the CATCH block, but no action is being taken there. You may also consider re-throwing the exception here, or logging. As written, it will roll back silently.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting XACT_ABORT ON in the stored procedure. When SET XACT_ABORT is ON and T-SQL statement raises a run-time error, SQL Server automatically rolls back the current transaction. Try it as follows:

```
USE AdventureWorks2016CTP3
GO
CREATE PROC spAddCustomer
@FirstName varchar = INPUT,
@LastName varchar = INPUT,
@EmailAddress varchar = INPUT,
@PhoneNumber varchar = INPUT
AS

SET NOCOUNT ON 
SET XACT_ABORT ON
BEGIN TRY
BEGIN TRANSACTION 
INSERT INTO sales.CustomerPII (FirstName,LastName,EmailAddress,PhoneNumber)
VALUES(@FirstName, @LastName, @EmailAddress, @PhoneNumber);
COMMIT TRANSACTION
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH

END CATCH;
```